# How many pesukim appear multiple times in Tanach

Tags: number, tanach

How many pesukim appear multiple times in Tanach? I'm referring to pesukim which are exactly the same in multiple (at least two) places; for example, הודו לה׳ כי טוב כי לעולם חסדו. The cantillation (trop) need not be the same.

Comment: Will you accept those that have variant _matres lectionis_?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I'll just treat this as a programming assignment. If we use mechon-mamre's masoretic text without vowels; if we ignore punctuation and paragraph marks; if we use the *ksiv* and not *kri* (occasionally there's a note -- "the scroll will say *this*, but read *that* out-loud instead), I'm getting 135 such verses. A lot of them you'd expect to find repeated a lot, e.g. "God told Moses to say", or verses repeated verbatim between Chronicles and some earlier book it's referencing, or the twelve princes of Israel who each offer the exact same sacrifice. Anyhow, here's the printout:

```
וידבר יהוה אל משה לאמר  69  ויקרא כב,כו | ויקרא ח,א | ויקרא כ,א | ויקרא כג,כו | ויקרא כג,כג | ויקרא כא,טז | ויקרא ד,א | ויקרא יז,א | ויקרא ו,א | ויקרא כד,א | ויקרא כד,יג | ויקרא ז,כח | ויקרא ז,כב | ויקרא ו,יז | ויקרא ו,יב | ויקרא ה,יד | ויקרא יב,א | ויקרא יח,א | ויקרא כב,א | ויקרא כג,לג | ויקרא כג,ט | ויקרא כג,א | ויקרא יט,א | ויקרא כז,א | ויקרא יד,א | ויקרא כב,יז | ויקרא ה,כ | במדבר ג,ה | במדבר כח,א | במדבר יז,טז | במדבר לה,ט | במדבר כה,י | במדבר ח,ה | במדבר ח,א | במדבר טז,כג | במדבר כו,נב | במדבר א,מח | במדבר טו,יז | במדבר יז,א | במדבר יז,ט | במדבר לד,טז | במדבר ה,יא | במדבר לד,א | במדבר י,א | במדבר יג,א | במדבר לא,א | במדבר ו,כב | במדבר ה,א | במדבר כ,ז | במדבר ו,א | במדבר ה,ה | במדבר כה,טז | במדבר טו,א | במדבר ג,יא | במדבר יח,כה | במדבר ט,ט | במדבר ד,כא | במדבר ג,מד | במדבר ח,כג | שמות ו,י | שמות ל,כב | שמות לא,א | שמות מ,א | שמות כה,א | שמות ל,יז | שמות ל,יא | שמות יג,א | שמות טז,יא | שמות יד,א
ויהי דבר יהוה אלי לאמר  45  זכריה ו,ט | זכריה ד,ח | ירמיהו ב,א | ירמיהו טז,א | ירמיהו כד,ד | ירמיהו יג,ח | ירמיהו א,ד | יחזקאל לג,כג | יחזקאל כא,א | יחזקאל לה,א | יחזקאל יב,כו | יחזקאל יב,א | יחזקאל יד,יב | יחזקאל כב,כג | יחזקאל כג,א | יחזקאל לג,א | יחזקאל כח,א | יחזקאל יח,א | יחזקאל לד,א | יחזקאל כב,א | יחזקאל יז,א | יחזקאל כד,טו | יחזקאל לח,א | יחזקאל כא,ו | יחזקאל טו,א | יחזקאל כז,א | יחזקאל ו,א | יחזקאל כא,יג | יחזקאל יז,יא | יחזקאל ל,א | יחזקאל כב,יז | יחזקאל כה,א | יחזקאל יב,כא | יחזקאל לו,טז | יחזקאל יב,יז | יחזקאל כא,כג | יחזקאל יג,א | יחזקאל כ,ב | יחזקאל כח,כ | יחזקאל טז,א | יחזקאל יד,ב | יחזקאל ז,א | יחזקאל כח,יא | יחזקאל לז,טו | יחזקאל יא,יד
שעיר עזים אחד לחטאת 12  במדבר ז,נח | במדבר ז,נב | במדבר ז,ע | במדבר ז,מ | במדבר ז,פב | במדבר ז,טז | במדבר ז,לד | במדבר ז,כב | במדבר ז,כח | במדבר ז,סד | במדבר ז,מו | במדבר ז,עו
פר אחד בן בקר איל אחד כבש אחד בן שנתו לעלה  12  במדבר ז,נז | במדבר ז,נא | במדבר ז,פא | במדבר ז,טו | במדבר ז,לט | במדבר ז,לג | במדבר ז,כא | במדבר ז,כז | במדבר ז,סט | במדבר ז,סג | במדבר ז,מה | במדבר ז,עה
כף אחת עשרה זהב מלאה קטרת   12  במדבר ז,סב | במדבר ז,נו | במדבר ז,פ | במדבר ז,יד | במדבר ז,כ | במדבר ז,נ | במדבר ז,לב | במדבר ז,לח | במדבר ז,כו | במדבר ז,סח | במדבר ז,מד | במדבר ז,עד
קרבנו קערת כסף אחת שלשים ומאה משקלה מזרק אחד כסף שבעים שקל בשקל הקדש שניהם מלאים סלת בלולה בשמן למנחה   10  במדבר ז,סא | במדבר ז,נה | במדבר ז,לא | במדבר ז,לז | במדבר ז,כה | במדבר ז,סז | במדבר ז,מג | במדבר ז,מט | במדבר ז,עג | במדבר ז,עט
למנצח מזמור לדוד    9   תהילים יט,א | תהילים כ,א | תהילים קמ,א | תהילים כא,א | תהילים נא,א | תהילים לא,א | תהילים סד,א | תהילים יג,א | תהילים מא,א
ויען איוב ויאמר 9   איוב כג,א | איוב יט,א | איוב כא,א | איוב כו,א | איוב טז,א | איוב ו,א | איוב ט,א | איוב יב,א | איוב ג,ב
וידבר יהוה אל משה ואל אהרן לאמר 9   ויקרא יג,א | ויקרא טו,א | ויקרא יד,לג | במדבר ד,יז | במדבר ד,א | במדבר טז,כ | במדבר ב,א | במדבר יט,א | במדבר יד,כו
ויאמר יהוה אל משה לאמר  5   במדבר ז,ד | במדבר לא,כה | במדבר טו,לז | במדבר כז,ו | שמות לא,יב
יודו ליהוה חסדו ונפלאותיו לבני אדם  4   תהילים קז,ח | תהילים קז,טו | תהילים קז,כא | תהילים קז,לא
ומנחתם ונסכיהם לפרים לאילם ולכבשים במספרם כמשפט 4   במדבר כט,כא | במדבר כט,כז | במדבר כט,יח | במדבר כט,ל
ויהי דבר יהוה אל ירמיהו לאמר    4   ירמיהו כט,ל | ירמיהו לב,כו | ירמיהו לה,יב | ירמיהו לג,כג
הודו ליהוה כי טוב כי לעולם חסדו 4   תהילים קיח,א | תהילים קלו,א | תהילים קיח,כט | דברי הימים א טז,לד
הדבר אשר היה אל ירמיהו מאת יהוה לאמר    4   ירמיהו יח,א | ירמיהו ז,א | ירמיהו ל,א | ירמיהו יא,א
רק הבמות לא סרו עוד העם מזבחים ומקטרים בבמות    3   מלכים ב יד,ד | מלכים ב יב,ד | מלכים ב טו,ד
מבן שלשים שנה ומעלה ועד בן חמשים שנה כל הבא לצבא לעבדה באהל מועד    3   במדבר ד,לט | במדבר ד,לה | במדבר ד,מג
למנצח לבני קרח מזמור    3   תהילים מט,א | תהילים פה,א | תהילים מז,א
ושעיר חטאת אחד מלבד עלת התמיד ומנחתה ונסכה  3   במדבר כט,כב | במדבר כט,לח | במדבר כט,כח
ששת ימים תעבד ועשית כל מלאכתך   2   שמות כ,ח | דברים ה,יב
ראשית בכורי אדמתך תביא בית יהוה אלהיך לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו  2   שמות כג,יט | שמות לד,כו
פה להם ולא ידברו עינים להם ולא יראו 2   תהילים קטו,ה | תהילים קלה,טז
עשרון עשרון לכבש האחד לשבעת הכבשים  2   במדבר כח,כט | במדבר כט,י
עשה ארץ בכחו מכין תבל בחכמתו ובתבונתו נטה שמים  2   ירמיהו נא,טו | ירמיהו י,יב
עירא היתרי גרב היתרי    2   דברי הימים א יא,מ | שמואל ב כג,לח
נדרי ליהוה אשלם נגדה נא לכל עמו 2   תהילים קטז,יד | תהילים קטז,יח
מעט שנות מעט תנומות מעט חבק ידים לשכב   2   משלי ו,י | משלי כד,לג
מה תשתוחחי נפשי ומה תהמי עליהוחילי לאלהים כי עוד אודנו ישועת פני ואלהי  2   תהילים מג,ה | תהילים מב,יב
למנצח בנגינת משכיל לדוד 2   תהילים נה,א | תהילים נד,א
לא תשא את שם יהוה אלהיך לשוא כי לא ינקה יהוה את אשר ישא את שמו לשוא 2   שמות כ,ו | דברים ה,י
כמוהם יהיו עשיהם כל אשר בטח בהם 2   תהילים קלה,יח | תהילים קטו,ח
כל הנתינים ובני עבדי שלמה שלש מאות תשעים ושנים  2   עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,נח | עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,ס
כי שמרתי דרכי יהוה ולא רשעתי מאלהי  2   תהילים יח,כב | שמואל ב כב,כב
כי כל אלהי העמים אלילים ויהוה שמים עשה  2   תהילים צו,ה | דברי הימים א טז,כו
ישלח ממרום יקחני ימשני ממים רבים    2   תהילים יח,יז | שמואל ב כב,יז
יש דרך ישר לפני איש ואחריתה דרכי מות    2   משלי יד,יב | משלי טז,כה
יודוך עמים אלהים יודוך עמים כלם 2   תהילים סז,ו | תהילים סז,ד
יהוה צבאות עמנו משגב לנו אלהי יעקב סלה  2   תהילים מו,יב | תהילים מו,ח
זה הדבר אשר דבר יהוה עליו בזה לך לעגה לך בתולת בת ציון אחריך ראש הניעה בת ירושלם    2   מלכים ב יט,כא | ישעיהו לז,כב
ותכלת וארגמן ותולעת שני ושש ועזים   2   שמות לה,ו | שמות כה,ד
ותבא העיר במצור עד עשתי עשרה שנה למלך צדקיהו    2   מלכים ב כה,ב | ירמיהו נב,ה
וששה קנים יצאים מצדיה שלשה קני מנרה מצדה האחד ושלשה קני מנרה מצדה השני  2   שמות כה,לב | שמות לז,יח
ושעיר עזים אחד חטאת מלבד עלת התמיד מנחתה ונסכה  2   במדבר כט,כה | במדבר כט,טז
וערת אילם מאדמים וערת תחשים ועצי שטים   2   שמות לה,ז | שמות כה,ה
ונר הוליד את קיש וקיש הוליד את שאול ושאול הוליד את יהונתן ואת מלכישוע ואת אבינדב ואת אשבעל  2   דברי הימים א ח,לג | דברי הימים א ט,לט
ונגה ונפג ויפיע 2   דברי הימים א יד,ו | דברי הימים א ג,ז
ומלחמה היתה בין אסא ובין בעשא מלך ישראל כל ימיהם    2   מלכים א טו,טז | מלכים א טו,לב
ולעבר ילד שני בנים שם האחד פלג כי בימיו נפלגה הארץ ושם אחיו יקטן    2   דברי הימים א א,יט | בראשית י,כה
וכל הנבאים נבאים כן לאמר עלה רמת גלעד והצלח ונתן יהוה ביד המלך  2   מלכים א כב,יב | דברי הימים ב יח,יא
ויתן המלך את הכסף בירושלם כאבנים ואת הארזים נתן כשקמים אשר בשפלה לרב    2   מלכים א י,כז | דברי הימים ב ט,כז
וישב רבשקה וימצא את מלך אשור נלחם על לבנה כי שמע כי נסע מלכיש   2   מלכים ב יט,ח | ישעיהו לז,ח
וישב יהושע וכל ישראל עמו אל המחנה הגלגלה    2   יהושוע י,טו | יהושוע י,מג
וישא משלו ויאמר נאם בלעם בנו בער ונאם הגבר שתם העין 2   במדבר כד,ג | במדבר כד,טו
ויקטן ילד את אלמודד ואת שלף ואת חצרמות ואת ירח  2   דברי הימים א א,כ | בראשית י,כו
ויצא הרוח ויעמד לפני יהוה ויאמר אני אפתנו ויאמר יהוה אליו במה   2   מלכים א כב,כא | דברי הימים ב יח,כ
ויעש הרע בעיני יהוה ככל אשר עשו אבתיו   2   מלכים ב כג,לז | מלכים ב כג,לב
ויעש הישר בעיני יהוה ככל אשר עשה אמציהו אביו    2   מלכים ב טו,ג | דברי הימים ב כו,ד
ויען צפר הנעמתי ויאמר   2   איוב כ,א | איוב יא,א
ויען בלדד השחי ויאמר    2   איוב כה,א | איוב יח,א
ויען אליפז התימני ויאמר 2   איוב טו,א | איוב ד,א
ויען איוב את יהוה ויאמר 2   איוב מב,א | איוב מ,ג
ויעמידה ליעקב לחק לישראל ברית עולם  2   תהילים קה,י | דברי הימים א טז,יז
ויספה פליטת בית יהודה הנשארה שרש למטה ועשה פרי למעלה    2   מלכים ב יט,ל | ישעיהו לז,לא
ויסף איוב שאת משלו ויאמר    2   איוב כז,א | איוב כט,א
ויסע וילך וישב סנחריב מלך אשור וישב בנינוה  2   מלכים ב יט,לו | ישעיהו לז,לז
וימת שמלה וימלך תחתיו שאול מרחבות הנהר  2   דברי הימים א א,מח | בראשית לו,לז
וימת שאול וימלך תחתיו בעל חנן בן עכבור  2   דברי הימים א א,מט | בראשית לו,לח
וימת הדד וימלך תחתיו שמלה ממשרקה    2   דברי הימים א א,מז | בראשית לו,לו
וימת בלע וימלך תחתיו יובב בן זרח מבצרה  2   דברי הימים א א,מד | בראשית לו,לג
ויט שמים וירד וערפל תחת רגליו   2   תהילים יח,י | שמואל ב כב,י
ויזעקו אל יהוה בצר להם ממצקותיהם יושיעם 2   תהילים קז,יג | תהילים קז,יט
ויזבח ויקטר בבמות ועל הגבעות ותחת כל עץ רענן    2   מלכים ב טז,ד | דברי הימים ב כח,ד
ויואב בן צרויה על הצבא ויהושפט בן אחילוד מזכיר  2   דברי הימים א יח,טו | שמואל ב ח,טז
ויהי כשמע המלך חזקיהו ויקרע את בגדיו ויתכס בשק ויבא בית יהוה    2   מלכים ב יט,א | ישעיהו לז,א
ויהי דבר יהוה צבאות אלי לאמר    2   זכריה ח,יח | זכריה ז,ד
ויהי דבר יהוה אליו לאמר 2   מלכים א יז,ב | מלכים א יז,ח
ויהי דבר יהוה אל אליהו התשבי לאמר   2   מלכים א כא,יז | מלכים א כא,כח
וידבר יהוה אל משה בערבת מואב על ירדן ירחו לאמר  2   במדבר לג,נ | במדבר לה,א
ויבן מזבחות לכל צבא השמים בשתי חצרות בית יהוה   2   מלכים ב כא,ה | דברי הימים ב לג,ה
ויבאו עבדי המלך חזקיהו אל ישעיהו    2   מלכים ב יט,ה | ישעיהו לז,ה
ויאמרו אליו כה אמר חזקיהו יום צרה ותוכחה ונאצה היום הזה כי באו בנים עד משבר וכח אין ללדה    2   מלכים ב יט,ג | ישעיהו לז,ג
ויאמר קנא קנאתי ליהוה אלהי צבאות כי עזבו בריתך בני ישראל את מזבחתיך הרסו ואת נביאיך הרגו בחרב ואותר אני לבדי ויבקשו את נפשי לקחתה   2   מלכים א יט,י | מלכים א יט,יד
ויאמר מיכיהו אם שוב תשוב בשלום לא דבר יהוה בי ויאמר שמעו עמים כלם   2   מלכים א כב,כח | דברי הימים ב יח,כז
ויאמר כלב אשר יכה את קרית ספר ולכדה ונתתי לו את עכסה בתי לאשה   2   שופטים א,יב | יהושוע טו,טז
ויאמר יהושפט האין פה נביא ליהוה עוד ונדרשה מאתו 2   מלכים א כב,ז | דברי הימים ב יח,ו
ויאמר יהושפט אל מלך ישראל דרש נא כיום את דבר יהוה   2   מלכים א כב,ה | דברי הימים ב יח,ד
ויאמר אליו המלך עד כמה פעמים אני משביעך אשר לא תדבר אלי רק אמת בשם יהוה 2   מלכים א כב,טז | דברי הימים ב יח,טו
ויאמר אליהם רבשקה אמרו נא אל חזקיהו כה אמר המלך הגדול מלך אשור מה הבטחון הזה אשר בטחת   2   מלכים ב יח,יט | ישעיהו לו,ד
והנותרת מן המנחה לאהרן ולבניו קדש קדשים מאשי יהוה   2   ויקרא ב,ג | ויקרא ב,י
והטור השני נפך ספיר ויהלם   2   שמות לט,יא | שמות כח,יח
והטור השלישי לשם שבו ואחלמה 2   שמות כח,יט | שמות לט,יב
ובני ישראל הישבים בערי יהודה וימלך עליהם רחבעם  2   מלכים א יב,יז | דברי הימים ב י,יז
ובמנרה ארבעה גבעים משקדים כפתריה ופרחיה 2   שמות כה,לד | שמות לז,כ
ואת שתי הכלית ואת החלב אשר עלהן אשר על הכסלים ואת היתרת על הכבד על הכלית יסירנה 2   ויקרא ג,טו | ויקרא ג,י
ואת פתרסים ואת כסלחים אשר יצאו משם פלשתים ואת כפתרים    2   דברי הימים א א,יב | בראשית י,יד
ואת היבוסי ואת האמרי ואת הגרגשי 2   דברי הימים א א,יד | בראשית י,טז
ואת החוי ואת הערקי ואת הסיני    2   דברי הימים א א,טו | בראשית י,יז
ואת הדורם ואת אוזל ואת דקלה 2   דברי הימים א א,כא | בראשית י,כז
ואת בת היענה ואת התחמס ואת השחף ואת הנץ למינהו  2   ויקרא יא,טז | דברים יד,טו
וארפכשד ילד את שלח ושלח ילד את עבר  2   דברי הימים א א,יח | בראשית י,כד
וארבעים אדניהם כסף שני אדנים תחת הקרש האחד ושני אדנים תחת הקרש האחד 2   שמות לו,כו | שמות כו,כא
ואיך תשיב את פני פחת אחד עבדי אדני הקטנים ותבטח לך על מצרים לרכב ולפרשים    2   מלכים ב יח,כד | ישעיהו לו,ט
התהללו בשם קדשו ישמח לב מבקשי יהוה  2   תהילים קה,ג | דברי הימים א טז,י
השבעתי אתכם בנות ירושלם בצבאות או באילות השדה אם תעירו ואם תעוררו את האהבה עד שתחפץ 2   שיר השירים ג,ה | שיר השירים ב,ז
הכהנים בני ידעיה לבית ישוע תשע מאות שבעים ושלשה 2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,לט | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לו
הוא יהוה אלהינו בכל הארץ משפטיו 2   תהילים קה,ז | דברי הימים א טז,יד
הבל המה מעשה תעתעים בעת פקדתם יאבדו 2   ירמיהו י,טו | ירמיהו נא,יח
הבו ליהוה משפחות עמים הבו ליהוה כבוד ועז    2   תהילים צו,ז | דברי הימים א טז,כח
הבה לנו עזרת מצר ושוא תשועת אדם 2   תהילים קח,יג | תהילים ס,יג
דרשו יהוה ועזו בקשו פניו תמיד   2   תהילים קה,ד | דברי הימים א טז,יא
דברי נרגן כמתלהמים והם ירדו חדרי בטן    2   משלי כו,כב | משלי יח,ח
בני שפטיה שלש מאות שבעים ושנים  2   עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,ד | עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,ט
בני פשחור אלף מאתים ארבעים ושבעה    2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,מא | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לח
בני עילם אלף מאתים חמשים וארבעה 2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,יב | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,ז
בני עילם אחר אלף מאתים חמשים וארבעה 2   עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לא | עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,לד
בני נציח בני חטיפא  2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,נו | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,נד
בני ירחו שלש מאות ארבעים וחמשה  2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,לו | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לד
בני יפת גמר ומגוג ומדי ויון ותבל ומשך ותירס 2   דברי הימים א א,ה | בראשית י,ב
בני חרם שלש מאות ועשרים 2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,לה | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לב
בני זכי שבע מאות וששים  2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,יד | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,ט
בני ברקוס בני סיסרא בני תמח 2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,נה | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,נג
בני בקבוק בני חקופא בני חרחור   2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,נג | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,נא
בני אמר אלף חמשים ושנים 2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,מ | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,לז
בן עשרים ואחת שנה צדקיהו במלכו ואחת עשרה שנה מלך בירושלם ושם אמו חמיטל בת ירמיהו מלבנה  2   מלכים ב כד,יח | ירמיהו נב,א
בימים ההם אין מלך בישראל איש הישר בעיניו יעשה   2   שופטים יז,ו | שופטים כא,כה
ביום הראשון מקרא קדש כל מלאכת עבדה לא תעשו  2   ויקרא כג,לה | במדבר כח,יח
באלהים נעשה חיל והוא יבוס צרינו 2   תהילים קח,יד | תהילים ס,יד
את שבתתי תשמרו ומקדשי תיראו אני יהוה    2   ויקרא כו,ב | ויקרא יט,ל
את בגדי השרד לשרת בקדש את בגדי הקדש לאהרן הכהן ואת בגדי בניו לכהן   2   שמות לה,יט | שמות לט,מא
ארך היריעה האחת שמנה ועשרים באמה ורחב ארבע באמה היריעה האחת מדה אחת לכל היריעת  2   שמות כו,ב | שמות לו,ט
אנשי ענתות מאה עשרים ושמנה  2   עזרא / נחמיה נ ז,כז | עזרא / נחמיה ע ב,כג
אנכי יהוה אלהיך אשר הוצאתיך מארץ מצרים מבית עבדים לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים על פני 2   שמות כ,ב | דברים ה,ו
אלוף קנז אלוף תימן אלוף מבצר    2   דברי הימים א א,נג | בראשית לו,מב
אלוף אהליבמה אלוף אלה אלוף פינן 2   דברי הימים א א,נב | בראשית לו,מא
אלהים דבר בקדשו אעלזה אחלקה שכם ועמק סכות אמדד  2   תהילים ס,ח | תהילים קח,ח
```

Comment: Care to share your code?