# Are there two verses anywhere in Tanakh with the same words but different cantillation?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation

Are there two *pesukim* anywhere in Tanakh which contain exactly the same words, but which have different cantillation? I am particularly interested in cases where the different cantillation causes the meanings of the two verses to be different; however, given the fact that I have not been able to even find such a case in Tanakh, I will be happy to see an example even if the meaning is not substantively changed by the difference in cantillation.

Comment: All verses with same words https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35345/759 I think this should be closed as a duplicate of that. Any verse here would be included there. Just check the references. I'm also not sure if you're counting a verse in Tehillim also writed in Shmuel, for instance

Comment: I also vote to close as a duplicate of [How many pesukim appear multiple times in Tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35345/how-many-pesukim-appear-multiple-times-in-tanach)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think this question is a duplicate of that question. Granted an answer to this one would be included in that list, but it is a very long list and not easily checked.

Comment: how about mayim adirim in shmos and shoftim

Answer (score 3):

I went through the list of repeated verses from [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35381/4940). Besides verses that appear both in Psalms and in the other 21 books (see there for the list), which will obviously have different cantillation (the 21 books use a different cantillation system than Job, Proverbs, and Psalms), there is exactly one example with a cantillation difference between the verses: [Exodus 26:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%91) and [Exodus 36:9](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%95_%D7%98), and they differ only in the first word.

> שמות כו, ב
>
> אֹ֣רֶךְ ׀ הַיְרִיעָ֣ה הָֽאַחַ֗ת שְׁמֹנֶ֤ה וְעֶשְׂרִים֙ בָּֽאַמָּ֔ה וְרֹ֙חַב֙ אַרְבַּ֣ע בָּאַמָּ֔ה הַיְרִיעָ֖ה הָאֶחָ֑ת מִדָּ֥ה אַחַ֖ת לְכׇל־הַיְרִיעֹֽת׃
>
> שמות לו, ט
>
> אֹ֜רֶךְ הַיְרִיעָ֣ה הָֽאַחַ֗ת שְׁמֹנֶ֤ה וְעֶשְׂרִים֙ בָּֽאַמָּ֔ה וְרֹ֙חַב֙ אַרְבַּ֣ע בָּֽאַמָּ֔ה הַיְרִיעָ֖ה הָאֶחָ֑ת מִדָּ֥ה אַחַ֖ת לְכׇל־הַיְרִיעֹֽת׃

If you discount differences of matres lectiones, you'll have a few more verse duplicates (like Ps 105:1 vs Chron 1:16:8). I don't know if you'll find another example among that extended list.

Comment: And wouldn't you believe it, it was literally the last example I checked.