# Seeking examples of epistrophe in Tanach

Tags: tanach, language

While [epistrophe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistrophe) can include repetition of a word (or expression) in successive phrases or clauses I am seeking to identify the use of this literary technique in consecutive verses. Two examples to illustrate include Tehillim 118:10-12 which all conclude with the phrase בְּשֵׁ֥ם ה' כִּ֣י אֲמִילַֽם and 1 Shmuel 10:14-16 which all end with the word Shmuel.

Are there other examples of 3 or more *pesukim* which employ epistrophe outside of songs/poetry?

Comment: How about Micah 5:9-12? Ah that's anaphora

Comment: Do any of the "Ani Hashems" in Parshas Kedoshim qualify? It's a very common ending, but I'd have to check the maximum consecutive count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Google Sheet containing a **complete list** of epistrophes of 3+ pesukim in Tanach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ8EN5SpTMLauFyoQYgy1wNrmL4p8u2CMPp8ljO-PfUKiqfqOGpWd05IzilUHU4nnH8CZvO__FZK8xu/pubhtml)  that I posted. The large majority of these **89 occurrences** are not within sections of songs/poetry. Some of these have already been mentioned earlier in this discussion.

I have noted there in **bold**/red font where the 3+ pasuk criteria is enabled or extended by the final word in a pasuk having a common root or a common spelling as opposed to an exact letter/vowel match.

*As a bonus and just for fun, I added a new tab to the spreadsheet called **ע"פ גמטריא** that contains the **only two occurrences in Tanach** where three consecutive pesukim end with words having the **same gematria** even though not all the three actual words are the same:*

- gematria = **215**: **יחזקאל:א:כד-כו** (*כנפיהן, כנפיהן, מלמעלה*)
- gematria = **61**: **תהלים:פו:א-ג** (*אני, אליך, היום*)

For your interest, also [see this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128873/six-verses-with-the-same-ending-except-one-difference/) which deals with consecutive pesukim which match on their final three or more words.

Comment: You definitely saved me some time. Thank you for beating me to it ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is not an exhaustive list; just instances that I could find:

- As well as your first example, the beginning of that chapter [(118:1-4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.118.1) ends as well, with the words:

> כי לעולם חסדו

- The entirety of Tehillim [136](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.136.1) ends with the words

> כי לעולם חסדו.

- Psalms 115 verses [9-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.115.9) ends with the words:

> עזרם ומגנם הוא

- Deuteronomy [27:16-26](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.27.16)

> אָר֕וּר מַקְלֶ֥ה אָבִ֖יו וְאִמּ֑וֹ **וְאָמַ֥ר כׇּל־הָעָ֖ם אָמֵֽן**׃

> אָר֗וּר אֲשֶׁ֧ר לֹא־יָקִ֛ים אֶת־דִּבְרֵ֥י הַתּוֹרָֽה־הַזֹּ֖את לַעֲשׂ֣וֹת אוֹתָ֑ם **וְאָמַ֥ר כׇּל־הָעָ֖ם אָמֵֽן**׃

- Hosea [14:6-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Hosea.14.6)

> אֶהְיֶ֤ה כַטַּל֙ לְיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל יִפְרַ֖ח כַּשּׁוֹשַׁנָּ֑ה וְיַ֥ךְ שׇׁרָשָׁ֖יו כַּ**לְּבָנֽוֹן**׃

> יֵֽלְכוּ֙ יֹֽנְקוֹתָ֔יו וִיהִ֥י כַזַּ֖יִת הוֹד֑וֹ וְרֵ֥יחַֽ ל֖וֹ כַּ**לְּבָנֽוֹן**׃

> יָשֻׁ֙בוּ֙ יֹשְׁבֵ֣י בְצִלּ֔וֹ יְחַיּ֥וּ דָגָ֖ן וְיִפְרְח֣וּ כַגָּ֑פֶן זִכְר֖וֹ כְּיֵ֥ין **לְבָנֽוֹן**׃

- Leviticus [19:2-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2)

> דַּבֵּ֞ר אֶל־כׇּל־עֲדַ֧ת בְּנֵי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֛ל וְאָמַרְתָּ֥ אֲלֵהֶ֖ם קְדֹשִׁ֣ים תִּהְי֑וּ כִּ֣י קָד֔וֹשׁ **אֲנִ֖י יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם**׃

> אִ֣ישׁ אִמּ֤וֹ וְאָבִיו֙ תִּירָ֔אוּ וְאֶת־שַׁבְּתֹתַ֖י תִּשְׁמֹ֑רוּ **אֲנִ֖י יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם**׃

> אַל־תִּפְנוּ֙ אֶל־הָ֣אֱלִילִ֔ם וֵֽאלֹהֵי֙ מַסֵּכָ֔ה לֹ֥א תַעֲשׂ֖וּ לָכֶ֑ם **אֲנִ֖י יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם**׃

- Genesis [3:11-13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.11)

> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר מִ֚י הִגִּ֣יד לְךָ֔ כִּ֥י עֵירֹ֖ם אָ֑תָּה הֲמִן־הָעֵ֗ץ אֲשֶׁ֧ר צִוִּיתִ֛יךָ לְבִלְתִּ֥י אֲכׇל־מִמֶּ֖נּוּ **אָכָֽלְ**תָּ׃

> וַיֹּ֖אמֶר הָֽאָדָ֑ם הָֽאִשָּׁה֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר נָתַ֣תָּה עִמָּדִ֔י הִ֛וא נָֽתְנָה־לִּ֥י מִן־הָעֵ֖ץ וָ**אֹכֵֽל**׃

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יְהֹוָ֧ה אֱלֹהִ֛ים לָאִשָּׁ֖ה מַה־זֹּ֣את עָשִׂ֑ית וַתֹּ֙אמֶר֙ הָֽאִשָּׁ֔ה הַנָּחָ֥שׁ הִשִּׁיאַ֖נִי וָ**אֹכֵֽל**׃

- Genesis 41:43-46
- Exodus 8:1-3
- Exodus 9:14-16
- Exodus [12:43-45](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.43)

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהֹוָה֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֣ה וְאַהֲרֹ֔ן זֹ֖את חֻקַּ֣ת הַפָּ֑סַח כׇּל־בֶּן־נֵכָ֖ר **לֹא־יֹ֥אכַל בּֽוֹ**׃

> תּוֹשָׁ֥ב וְשָׂכִ֖יר **לֹא־יֹ֥אכַל בּֽוֹ**׃

- Exodus [12:43-46](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.43)

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהֹוָה֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֣ה וְאַהֲרֹ֔ן זֹ֖את חֻקַּ֣ת הַפָּ֑סַח כׇּל־בֶּן־נֵכָ֖ר לֹא־יֹ֥אכַל **בּֽוֹ**׃

> בְּבַ֤יִת אֶחָד֙ יֵאָכֵ֔ל לֹא־תוֹצִ֧יא מִן־הַבַּ֛יִת מִן־הַבָּשָׂ֖ר ח֑וּצָה וְעֶ֖צֶם לֹ֥א תִשְׁבְּרוּ־**בֽוֹ**׃

- Exodus [13:16-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.16)

> וְהָיָ֤ה לְאוֹת֙ עַל־יָ֣דְכָ֔ה וּלְטוֹטָפֹ֖ת בֵּ֣ין עֵינֶ֑יךָ כִּ֚י בְּחֹ֣זֶק יָ֔ד הוֹצִיאָ֥נוּ יְהֹוָ֖ה מִ**מִּצְרָֽיִם**׃

> וַיַּסֵּ֨ב אֱלֹהִ֧ים ׀ אֶת־הָעָ֛ם דֶּ֥רֶךְ הַמִּדְבָּ֖ר יַם־ס֑וּף וַחֲמֻשִׁ֛ים עָל֥וּ בְנֵי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל מֵאֶ֥רֶץ **מִצְרָֽיִם**׃

- Exodus [21:14-17](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.14). Verses 14-17 all have the same root. Verses 15-17 are the same word form:

> וְכִֽי־יָזִ֥ד אִ֛ישׁ עַל־רֵעֵ֖הוּ לְהׇרְג֣וֹ בְעׇרְמָ֑ה מֵעִ֣ם מִזְבְּחִ֔י תִּקָּחֶ֖נּוּ **לָמֽוּת**׃

> וּמַכֵּ֥ה אָבִ֛יו וְאִמּ֖וֹ מ֥וֹת **יוּמָֽת**׃

> וּמְקַלֵּ֥ל אָבִ֛יו וְאִמּ֖וֹ מ֥וֹת **יוּמָֽת**׃

- Exodus [27:17-19](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.27.17)
- Exodus [29:23-25](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.23)
- Exodus [38:10-12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.38.10)
- Leviticus [2:9-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.2.9)
- Leviticus [7:7-9](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.7.7) same root.
- Leviticus [9:5-7](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.9.5)
- Leviticus [11:4-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.4)
- Leviticus [11:14-16](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.14) same root.
- Leviticus [13:39-41](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.13.39)
- Leviticus [15:5-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.15.5)
- Leviticus [15:16-19](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.15.16)
- Leviticus [15:21-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.15.21)
- Leviticus [18:12-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.12)
- Leviticus [19:2-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2)
- Leviticus [20:11-13](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.11)
- Leviticus [23:16-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.16)
- Numbers [9:19-22](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.9.19) same root.
- Numbers [28:6-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.6)
- Numbers [31:32-35](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.32) same root. 33-35 same form.
- Numbers [35:16-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.35.16)

Comment: But that's poetic

Comment: @shmosel which one?

Comment: The ones in Tehillim

Comment: @shmosel the OP themselves quoted Tehillim

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

במדבר פרק ח פסוק יט

וָאֶתְּנָ֨ה אֶת־הַלְוִיִּ֜ם נְתֻנִ֣ים ׀ לְאַהֲרֹ֣ן וּלְבָנָ֗יו מִתּוֹךְ֮ **בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒** לַעֲבֹ֞ד אֶת־עֲבֹדַ֤ת **בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵל֙** בְּאֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֔ד וּלְכַפֵּ֖ר **עַל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל** וְלֹ֨א יִהְיֶ֜ה **בִּבְנֵ֤י יִשְׂרָאֵל֙** נֶ֔גֶף בְּגֶ֥שֶׁת **בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל** אֶל־הַקֹּֽדֶשׁ׃

תהלים פרק מב–מג

(א) לַמְנַצֵּחַ מַשְׂכִּיל לִבְנֵי קֹרַח.
(ב) כְּאַיָּל תַּעֲרֹג עַל אֲפִיקֵי מָיִם כֵּן נַפְשִׁי תַעֲרֹג אֵלֶיךָ אֱלֹהִים.
(ג) צָמְאָה נַפְשִׁי לֵאלֹהִים לְאֵל חָי מָתַי אָבוֹא וְאֵרָאֶה פְּנֵי אֱלֹהִים.
(ד) הָיְתָה לִּי דִמְעָתִי לֶחֶם יוֹמָם וָלָיְלָה בֶּאֱמֹר אֵלַי כׇּל הַיּוֹם אַיֵּה אֱלֹהֶיךָ.
(ה) אֵלֶּה אֶזְכְּרָה וְאֶשְׁפְּכָה עָלַי נַפְשִׁי כִּי אֶעֱבֹר בַּסָּךְ אֶדַּדֵּם עַד בֵּית אֱלֹהִים בְּקוֹל רִנָּה וְתוֹדָה הָמוֹן חוֹגֵג.
**(ו) מַה תִּשְׁתּוֹחֲחִי נַפְשִׁי וַתֶּהֱמִי עָלָי הוֹחִלִי לֵאלֹהִים כִּי עוֹד אוֹדֶנּוּ יְשׁוּעוֹת פָּנָיו.**
(ז) אֱלֹהַי עָלַי נַפְשִׁי תִשְׁתּוֹחָח עַל כֵּן אֶזְכׇּרְךָ מֵאֶרֶץ יַרְדֵּן וְחֶרְמוֹנִים מֵהַר מִצְעָר.
(ח) תְּהוֹם אֶל תְּהוֹם קוֹרֵא לְקוֹל צִנּוֹרֶיךָ כׇּל מִשְׁבָּרֶיךָ וְגַלֶּיךָ עָלַי עָבָרוּ.
(ט) יוֹמָם יְצַוֶּה י״י חַסְדּוֹ וּבַלַּיְלָה שִׁירֹה עִמִּי תְּפִלָּה לְאֵל חַיָּי.
(י) אוֹמְרָה לְאֵל סַלְעִי לָמָה שְׁכַחְתָּנִי לָמָּה קֹדֵר אֵלֵךְ בְּלַחַץ אוֹיֵב.
(יא) בְּרֶצַח בְּעַצְמוֹתַי חֵרְפוּנִי צוֹרְרָי בְּאׇמְרָם אֵלַי כׇּל הַיּוֹם אַיֵּה אֱלֹהֶיךָ.
**(יב) מַה תִּשְׁתּוֹחֲחִי נַפְשִׁי וּמַה תֶּהֱמִי עָלָי הוֹחִילִי לֵאלֹהִים כִּי עוֹד אוֹדֶנּוּ יְשׁוּעֹת פָּנַי וֵאלֹהָי.**
(א) שׇׁפְטֵנִי אֱלֹהִים וְרִיבָה רִיבִי מִגּוֹי לֹא חָסִיד מֵאִישׁ מִרְמָה וְעַוְלָה תְפַלְּטֵנִי.
(ב) כִּי אַתָּה אֱלֹהֵי מָעוּזִּי לָמָה זְנַחְתָּנִי לָמָּה קֹדֵר אֶתְהַלֵּךְ בְּלַחַץ אוֹיֵב.
(ג) שְׁלַח אוֹרְךָ וַאֲמִתְּךָ הֵמָּה יַנְחוּנִי יְבִיאוּנִי אֶל הַר קׇדְשְׁךָ וְאֶל מִשְׁכְּנוֹתֶיךָ.
(ד) וְאָבוֹאָה אֶל מִזְבַּח אֱלֹהִים אֶל אֵל שִׂמְחַת גִּילִי וְאוֹדְךָ בְכִנּוֹר אֱלֹהִים אֱלֹהָי.
**(ה) מַה תִּשְׁתּוֹחֲחִי נַפְשִׁי וּמַה תֶּהֱמִי עָלָי הוֹחִילִי לֵאלֹהִים כִּי עוֹד אוֹדֶנּוּ יְשׁוּעֹת פָּנַי וֵאלֹהָי.**

Comment: This is a fun trivia verse, but the question sought three verses with repeating closing elements